# Laravel 5.4, no luck with Homestead

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, homestead

Everytime I try to install Homestead on 5.4, I cannot. Here is the error message I get from the terminal. I have tried to look at the path, but I see no issues. Aside from this, I have no clue what to do. Any troubleshooting tips would be appreciated.
[link to issue (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOjML.png)

Comment: Well, it clearly states that it requires the `openssl` extension. So just install it.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to fix this

1. Disable tls `composer config -g -- disable-tls true` - not recommended
2. Enable the openssl extension in your php.ini file `extension=php_openssl.so`